# Connecting to the IBM MQ using wmq jmsra resource adapter from jboss

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq

I would like to connect to the IBM MQ using a wmq jmsra resource adapter.
Am trying to connect to the IBM MQ server that is on version 8.0.0.5, which adapter can I use ?

Can I use adapter of version for example 7.5 ?

Problem is that for example with change from adaper 7 to 8 I also need to change version of jboss from 6 to 7 based on this :
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/deploy_the_websphere_mq_resource_adapter

My cipher should not be a problem I think as I see that is supported by for example version 7.5
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IV66840
Also that I see that ibm is creating fixes for versions 7.5 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IBM MQ 7.5.0.8 jmsra resource adapter can connect to an IBM MQ queue manager at a higher level such as v8.0.0.5.

---

IBM Technote "[MQ 7.x, MQ 8.0 and MQ 9.0 compatibility with previous versions - including usage of CCDT files, JMS .bindings, SSL/TLS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21312967)" states:

> **Compatibility statement:**
>
> WebSphere MQ V7.0, V7.1, V7.5, V8.0 and V9.0 queue managers and
>   clients inter operate with queue managers and clients from any
>   previous level of the WebSphere MQ or MQSeries products.
>
> This means that ...
>
> - A 7.0, 7.1, ***7.5***, 8.0 and 9.0 client can connect to all queue managers, non-version 7, as well as version 7.0, 7.1, 7.5, ***8.0*** and 9.0
> - A 7.0, 7.1, 7.5, 8.0 and 9.0 queue manager can interact with all clients, non-version 7, as well as version 7.0, 7.1, 7.5, 8.0 and 9.0

---

Note however that IBM MQ v7.5 has an end of service date of April 30th 2018.  I would recommend you use either v8.0 or v9.0 which have not had end of service dates announced yet.  Newer MQ client versions can connect to older MQ queue managers.  You can download a java only install of MQ 8.0 or MQ 9.0 jar files at the links below:

- [IBM MQ v8.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500)
- [IBM MQ v9.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176)

---

Note that to use TLS ciphersuites with a non-IBM JRE (ex: Oracle JRE) you will need to be at a minimum of the following levels of IBM MQ:

```
Version    Maintenance Level
v7.5       7.5.0.5
v8.0       8.0.0.2
v9.0       9.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thx @JoshMc,
Is there a page which describes compatibility between adapters and queue managers ? as I would like to use 7.5.0.8 to connect to IBM MQ menager of version 8.0.0.7 and use TLS also for that

Comment: @bijesanu I updated my answer with a link to a Technote that talks about version compatibility.  As I had stated at the start of my answer you CAN connect from 7.5 RA to v8.0 queue manager with out issue.  But also note as I stated v7.5 only has 4.5 months of support left from IBM, I would recommend you go with v9.0 even if it means you need to upgrade to Java 7 since you will have to upgrade to Java 7 in a few months to keep yourself at a supported level.